# Adaboost updating the weight. How to use Induction to proof two equation are the same?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, adaboost

I have these equation for updating the weight the same.
$$w^{(b+1)}_{i} = \frac{w_i^{(b)} \exp(-\alpha_by_ih_b(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_j^{(b)} \exp(-\alpha_by_jh_b(x_j))}$$

and

$$w^{(b+1)}_{i}=\frac{\exp(-y_if_b(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_jf_b(x_i))} $$

Where,
$$f_b = \sum_{p\le b}\alpha_bh_b$$

I want to use induction to proof they are the same.

For the base case $w^{(1)}=(\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n}) \in R^n $ now we want to update the weight
$$w^{(1+1)}_{i} = \frac{w_i^{(1)} \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_j^{(1)} \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))}= \frac{\frac{1}{n} \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n} \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} $$
thus,
$$w^{(1+1)}_{i} = \frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} $$
updating the weight on the second equation,
$$w^{(1+1)}_{i}=\frac{\exp(-y_if_b(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_jf_b(x_i))} $$
substituting the definition of $f_1 = \sum_{p\le 1}\alpha_1h_1 =\alpha_1h_1  $
$$w^{(1+1)}_{i}=\frac{\exp(-y_i\alpha_1h_1(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_j\alpha_1h_1(x_i))} $$

now the two equations are the same. Then we have to update again,

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{w_i^{(2)} \exp(-\alpha_2y_ih_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_j^{(2)}\exp(-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j))}$$
we can substitute the definition of $w^{(2)}_i =\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}
{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} $

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} \exp(-\alpha_2y_ih_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_j^{(2)} 
\exp(-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j))}$$
We can also substitute $w^{(2)}_{j} =\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} $

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} \exp(-\alpha_2y_ih_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))} 
\exp(-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j))}$$

This is a constant $C= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))$ we can substitute that

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))}{C}\exp(-\alpha_2y_ih_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{ \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j))}{C} 
\exp(-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j))}$$

thus we get,

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{\exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i))\exp(-\alpha_2y_ih_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j)) 
\exp(-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j))}$$
using the power rules,

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{\exp(-y_i\alpha_1h_1(x_i)-y_i\alpha_2h_2(x_i)))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j)-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j)) 
}=\frac{\exp(-y_i(\alpha_1h_1(x_i)+\alpha_2h_2(x_i)))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_j(\alpha_1h_1(x_j)+\alpha_2h_2(x_j))) 
}$$
and now we substitute $f_2=\sum_{p\le 2}^{}\alpha_ph_p =\alpha_1h_1 +\alpha_2h_2 $
thus we get,

$$w^{(2+1)}_{i} = \frac{\exp(-y_if_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_jf_2(x_j)) 
}=\frac{\exp(-\alpha_1y_ih_1(x_i)-\alpha_2y_ih_2(x_i))}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \exp(-y_j(-\alpha_1y_jh_1(x_j)-\alpha_2y_jh_2(x_j)))) 
}$$

I can keep going this way to $w^{(4)}\ldots w^{(b)}$ but how do I make a proof by induction? I just don't know how to make formal proof.